# May I create a custom license plate myself (in Virginia) using a purchased blank plate?

Tags: driving, virginia, license-plates, dmv

I live in America (VA), and I wanted to replace my current license plate with a customized one.

I found an item on Amazon, which gives me a blank black license plate with white text.

The original content and my license text is still the same, however now the design would be different. Are there are laws that prohibit doing what I want to do?

I did some research and found that under the code of Virginia, § 46.2-722, it states:

> Any person who, with fraudulent intent, alters any license plate or decal issued by the
> Department or by any other state, forges or counterfeits any license plate or decal
> purporting to have been issued by the Department under the provisions of this title or by
> any other state under a similar law or who, with fraudulent intent, alters, falsifies, or
> forges any assignment thereof, or who holds or uses any license plate or decal knowing it to
> have been altered, forged, or falsified, shall be guilty of a Class 1 misdemeanor.

I'm confused, does it mean that I can't use a license plate that I don't own, or does it prohibit the usage of the license plate I want to get?

Comment: Most states sell license plates with custom text and/or a choice of background.

Comment: Are you customizing the registration number or just the background design of the plate?

Comment: When I lived in VA, black plates with white text were reserved for 'antique' vehicles.

Comment: Context: in many parts of Europe, license/number plates are purchased and produced privately. In some places, the vehicle registration authority inspects the plate and affixes a sticker to it. This allows some level of customization within regulatory parameters, e.g. plastic vs aluminum, glued-on letters vs stamped vs printed, backlighting, borders, labeling with UK vs GB vs ENG/SCO/CYM etc.

Comment: Even if it were legal to have a non-standard plate bearing your state issued plate number, the fact that you're asking suggests others woulc question it's legality too. You'd probably get pulled over and issued a citation by an officer who thinks it's not legal, see [Heien v. North Carolina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heien_v._North_Carolina#:~:text=North%20Carolina%2C%20574%20U.S.%2054,to%20justify%20a%20traffic%20stop.)

Comment: @Sidney It's a state dependent question. Many states allow period-accurate reproduction license plates on vintage vehicles (e.g. [KY](https://apps.legislature.ky.gov/law/statutes/statute.aspx?id=5928)). CA allows digital license plates.

Comment: @user71659 While North Carolina is the defendant in the above supreme court case, the point that the supreme court has ruled officers may have a reasonable misunderstanding of the law nationwide. The point still stands that in an edge case like this it's asking to be pulled over and cited, eliciting inconvenient court costs to fight the citation.

Comment: @Sidney VA has over 250 different custom license plates. My state's got 3 standard car plates, a separate personal truck plate. Of standard plates, they switched letter colors a few years ago, they started out embossed, they went digital, went back to embossed, and are now going digital. If somebody's going to claim a plate is fake, they're going to claim a plate is fake.

Comment: @user71659 Virginia is (was) particularly un-funny about this... https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/lifestyle/food/1996/10/30/red-e-or-not-kates-plates-in-trouble/a7eb0a6f-0d3c-44a7-973e-6e4f4aecaca1/

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> forges or counterfeits any license plate

That means you can't make your own.  Certainly any created plate in different colors or design will attract attention of the authorities as well.

You will need to use the license plate issued by the state.

Comment: Does this also cound when I just put it onto the front of the car?

Comment: In Texas, at least, the license plates have special reflective designs so that the toll cameras can scan them.  So front and back plates have to be state-issued.

Comment: Isn't "with fraudulent intent" key here?

Comment: @B.Goddard - not all states have a front license plate. My state does not, and many of the local Air Force base folks put plates they got in Europe on the front of their cars...

Comment: @Nuro007 Virginia requires both front and rear plates, so no, you can't use your own plate there.  You must go with one of the designs issued by the state.

Comment: @JonCuster But a lot of states do so it will just depend on what state your car is registered in. In the case of military it isn't uncommon for that to be from a different state then what they are in.

Comment: I _suspect_ but never bothered to find out, that if you use a front plate from a state that requires front plates while actually registered in a state that doesn't, you'll get in trouble in some way (although maybe only if you visit that state).  A front plate that clearly isn't valid is very different.

Comment: @JoeW not registering your car to where you live can be a breach of law in itself.

Comment: @Trish Active Military personnel have an official "Home of Record" which is where they joined the military from.  They can keep their vehicles registered to their HOR state longer than normal civilians where they currently live because their Military assignments often have them moving around the country multiple times in a short period.  I lived in three states in 6 years of my enlistment which were not my HOR and I never had to register my vehicle in any of them.

Comment: @Trish that is not the case for members of the military in the USA and they can have a vehicle and drivers license registered to a different state from where they are stationed. As a side note they can also change this as needed.

Comment: @CitizenRon that's only for military, not average joe. I said it *can* be a breach of law. not that it *is*. In California, you technically have to register your car within a certain timeframe, or you risk a fine, unless you are military.

Comment: @Bartors exactly. This answer is marked as the right one but is completely wrong. It requires BOTH "forging or  counterfitting" AND "fraudulent intent" to be affected by this law. The latter is absolutly not given, since OP just wants a design change for his legitimate license plate number

Comment: @Hobbamok I suggest that unless you're planning on fighting the intent side of the charge (with a lawyer) this is a losing proposition.  As with many comma-laden laws, this one isn't really clear, and courts tend to just hammer you.  Not to mention, once you're pulled over you are at the mercy of the officer.

Comment: @Bobson why is a plate from Europe "clearly not valid"?

Comment: @Trish many states if not most also allow students to keep their license and vehicle registration in their home state.

Comment: @phoog because they are considered to still live wherever they come from for studies. but *general* normal residents...

Comment: @phoog I suppose [it's technically possible](http://www.foreignborn.com/visas_imm/entering_us/7importingyourcar.htm#driversplates) for someone to import their car from Europe as a tourist and legally drive with European plates for a while.  But it's going to be vanishingly rare (except maybe around DC?).  By far the most likely explanation if you see car with a a Euro front plate is that it's from one of the 21 states that only require a back plate. But if you have a VA front plate in NC, but a NC back plate, you're going to be very confusing to people.

Answer (score 23):

Your confusion probably stems from trying to look at this issue from the wrong end.  Instead of looking at the VA Code related to details of license plate forgeries, look earlier in the code for [**§ 46.2-712 Requirements of license plates and decals**](https://law.lis.virginia.gov/vacode/title46.2/chapter6/section46.2-712/) which states that all graphic design details of the license plate is at "*the discretion of the Commissioner*".

Looking back further in chapter [**§ 46.2-711. Furnishing number and design of plates; displaying on vehicles required**](https://law.lis.virginia.gov/vacode/title46.2/chapter6/section46.2-711/), paragraph F states:  "*No vehicles shall be operated on the highways in the Commonwealth without displaying the license plates required by this chapter*" and that chapter refers to "*The Department shall furnish one license plate for every registered moped, motorcycle, autocycle, tractor truck, semitrailer, or trailer, and two license plates for every other registered motor vehicle*" so it appears that the only valid license plate allowed in VA is explicitly one that is issued by "The Department".

Also, you missed a very important part of [**§ 46.2-722. Altered or forged license plates or decals; use as evidence of knowledge.**](https://law.lis.virginia.gov/vacode/title46.2/chapter6/section46.2-722/)

"*The owner of a vehicle who operates it while it displays altered or forged license plates or decals shall be presumed to have knowledge of the alteration or forgery.*"

Since you would know that your proposed custom license plate is not approved by the Commissioner, you would almost certainly be found guilty of violating **46.2-722** as that would take care of the "*with fraudulent intent*" part of the Code.

Comment: "two license plates for every other registered motor vehicle" I'm confused - each two cars share license plates?

Comment: @AdamBarnes much of the world presumes two plates on a single vehicle, one each for the front and back.  Some US states only require one, on the rear.

Comment: @AdamBarnes if you follow the link, you'll see from the context that "every other motor vehicle" means "every motor vehicle that is not a moped, motorcycle, autocycle, tractor truck, semitrailer, or trailer."

Comment: @Criggie that's true, but that's not what's going on here.  Rather, Virginia requires one plate for mopeds, motorcycles, autocycles, tractor trucks, semitrailers, and trailers, and two for everything else.

Comment: @Criggie the quote says "every other vehicle", which has specific meaning.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  My edited quote made perfect sense to me, but probably because I read the original.

Comment: @CitizenRon that changed quote makes it make a lot more sense without reading the original, thank you.